# Is the EAP-Request/Identity and EAP-Response/Identity transmitted in the clear in a WPA2 entreprise Wi-Fi setup?

Tags: wireless, protocol-theory, ieee-802.11, ieee-802.1x

Looking at the WPA2 (Entreprise, let's say PEAP-MSCHAPv2) Wi-Fi protocol, I understand that since WPA2 uses Open System Authentication, and that 802.1X authentication takes place before the 4-way handshake, the initial `EAP-Request/Identity` and `EAP-Response/Identity` exchange takes place in the clear. Am I mistaken ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked by monitoring my phone connecting to `eduroam`, and the answer is yes, the outer identity is transmitted in some EAP `Response, Identity` message and is not encrypted. Which is probably why two identities are required: the "anonymous" identity for the outer identity request, and the inner identity.